UVC device has no output stream on linux, while working fine on windows
On windows, without needing to install drivers, I can plug it (an Avermedia GC553) in and it works as an ordinary camera device. On Linux, plugged into the same ports with the same cables (and with different ports and different cables) it is detected and I can select it in programs, but there is no output.
First of all here's some information on the device itself, running lsusb it gives:
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 07ca:0553 AVerMedia Technologies, Inc. Live Gamer Ultra-Video

Output of v4l2-ctl --device=/dev/video0 --all (The lines about resolution and frame rate change depending on what the last program it used set it to, however all the info about colour spaces and such stay the same):
Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Card type        : Live Gamer Ultra-Video: Live Ga
        Bus info         : usb-0000:38:00.0-2
        Driver version   : 6.11.0
        Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
                Video Capture
                Metadata Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
                Device Capabilities
        Device Caps      : 0x04200001
                Video Capture
                Streaming
                Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
        Driver name      : uvcvideo
        Model            : Live Gamer Ultra-Video: Live Ga
        Serial           : 5312258600354
        Bus info         : usb-0000:38:00.0-2
        Media version    : 6.11.0
        Hardware revision: 0x00000308 (776)
        Driver version   : 6.11.0
Interface Info:
        ID               : 0x03000002
        Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
        ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
        Name             : Live Gamer Ultra-Video: Live Ga
        Function         : V4L2 I/O
        Flags            : default
        Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
          Link 0x02000010: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 3' (Video Pixel Formatter): Data, Enabled, Immutable
Priority: 2
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
Format Video Capture:
        Width/Height      : 3840/2160
        Pixel Format      : 'NV12' (Y/UV 4:2:0)
        Field             : None
        Bytes per Line    : 3840
        Size Image        : 12441600
        Colorspace        : sRGB
        Transfer Function : Rec. 709
        YCbCr/HSV Encoding: Rec. 709
        Quantization      : Default (maps to Limited Range)
        Flags             : 
Crop Capability Video Capture:
        Bounds      : Left 0, Top 0, Width 3840, Height 2160
        Default     : Left 0, Top 0, Width 3840, Height 2160
        Pixel Aspect: 1/1
Selection Video Capture: crop_default, Left 0, Top 0, Width 3840, Height 2160, Flags: 
Selection Video Capture: crop_bounds, Left 0, Top 0, Width 3840, Height 2160, Flags: 
Streaming Parameters Video Capture:
        Capabilities     : timeperframe
        Frames per second: 30.000 (30/1)
        Read buffers     : 0

dmesg when plugging it in:
[ 1552.734649] usb 4-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 1552.747137] usb 4-2: LPM exit latency is zeroed, disabling LPM.
[ 1552.747431] usb 4-2: Int endpoint with wBytesPerInterval of 1024 in config 1 interface 4 altsetting 0 ep 135: setting to 262
[ 1552.748023] usb 4-2: New USB device found, idVendor=07ca, idProduct=0553, bcdDevice= 3.08
[ 1552.748040] usb 4-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1552.748049] usb 4-2: Product: Live Gamer Ultra-Video
[ 1552.748057] usb 4-2: Manufacturer: AVerMedia
[ 1552.748063] usb 4-2: SerialNumber: 5312258600354
[ 1552.754832] uvcvideo 4-2:1.1: Unknown video format 30313050-0000-0010-8000-00aa00389b71
[ 1552.754858] usb 4-2: Found UVC 1.00 device Live Gamer Ultra-Video (07ca:0553)
[ 1558.379692] hid-generic 0003:07CA:0553.0008: hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [AVerMedia Live Gamer Ultra-Video] on usb-0000:38:00.0-2/input4

and the messages I get when attempting to use it:
[ 1991.153524] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Failed to submit URB 0 (-2).
[ 2011.847393] uvcvideo 2-1:1.1: Non-zero status (-71) in video completion handler

Running ffplay /dev/video0/ i simply get
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x726d3c000c80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes).
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YV12 / 0x32315659), yuv420p, 640x480, 221184 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1000k tbn
[video4linux2,v4l2 @ 0x726d3c000c80] Dequeued v4l2 buffer contains corrupted data (0 bytes).
    Last message repeated 30 times
    nan M-V:    nan fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B  0B 

Showing me that basically no data is coming from it at all. I tried it again with vlc v4l2:///dev/video0 and got
main input error: Invalid PCR value in ES_OUT_SET_(GROUP_)PCR !

4 times in a row, with no other information.
Avermedia has not put out a driver for this device, however it works without one on linux, and I've heard had it work for others on linux as well. They recommend to update it to the latest firmware on windows, and then use it on linux, which I have done already. I'm hoping all these logs and such are enough, a lot of these errors have no results when looking it up.
I have gotten it to work a few times, but exclusively at 640x480 and very inconsistently. I recently reinstalled linux which fixed many other issues I've had in various areas but not this.
